# Redirect command line output to MVC controller

Tags: c#, visual-studio, model-view-controller, command-line, casperjs

I'm developing an internet application using MVC and C# with Visual Studio 2013. I need to implement a feature that enables to automatically login in a website. To do that, I use the CasperJs framework.

The following code creates a thread that will execute js code in a command line.

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Publish()
    {
        try
        {
            new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(x =>
            {
                ExecuteCommand("casperjs test.js");
            })).Start();

            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, e.Message);
        }
    }

    private void ExecuteCommand(string Command)
    {
        try
        {
            ProcessStartInfo processInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe", "/K " + Command);

            processInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            processInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            processInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;

            Process process = Process.Start(processInfo);

            string output = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();

            process.WaitForExit();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Trace.Listeners.Add(new TextWriterTraceListener(e.ToString()));
        }
    }
```

To be sure that eveything went right, I want to redirect the output produced in the command line to my controller. How do I do that? With the previous code the string output is always null.

Comment: What is it that you want to do with the output?  Is your code successfully gathering the information it needs from the external process in the `output` variable?  If so, then you don't need to "redirect" anything, you have the value you need in that variable.  What are you looking to do with that value?

Comment: The main goal is to be sure if the login was correctly done. Right now, I know that login was done because when I run the command directly in the command line, I am printing the title of the page. I need to know that information in the mvc controller side. I was trying to get that information with the output string, but it is always null.

Comment: Your implementation is a little different from what MSDN suggests (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.standardoutput%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).  Maybe try capturing the stream like in that sample?  That's mostly a guess, to be honest.  Are you sure this external process responds in standard output?  This doesn't appear to have anything to do with MVC but rather with just capturing the output of a process in C# code.

Comment: Honestly, i'm new in mvc, c# and jquery. I discover CasperJS to do this kind of stuff and I tried to use this framework following examples. But I did not understand yet how can I pass information between CasperJS to my controller, to give user feedback. I'm a bit confused.

Comment: Well, I'm not even really sure what CasperJS is to be honest, and I'm *definitely* not sure why you're using an external process to validate a login.  That's usually something an application does internally.  But to be clear, the *specific* problem you're facing is that you're trying to read the standard output from an external process (in a `Process` object).  It has nothing to do with MVC or jQuery. (Nothing in this question has *anything* to do with jQuery, I'm not sure why you even mentioned that.)  I don't have an answer for you on that, but hopefully helped you identify the question.

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't sure if you wanted to actually return the output of the command as a response to the Publish, but the altered 'ExecuteCommand' method should help to obtain the standard output from the process.  From there, you can do what you like based upon expected values that may be contained in that output.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Publish()
{
    try
    {
        string cmdResult = "";
        new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(x =>
        {
            cmdResult = ExecuteCommand("casperjs test.js");
        })).Start();

        var response = Request.CreateResponse<string>(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK, cmdResult);
        return response;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, e.Message);
    }
}

private string ExecuteCommand(string Command)
{
    string result = "";
    try
    {
        ProcessStartInfo processInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe", "/K " + Command);

        processInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        processInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        processInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        processInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;

        Process process = Process.Start(processInfo);
        process.WaitForExit();

        while (!process.StandardOutput.EndOfStream)
        {
            result += process.StandardOutput.ReadLine();
        }

        while (!process.StandardError.EndOfStream)
        {
            result += process.StandardError.ReadLine();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Trace.Listeners.Add(new TextWriterTraceListener(e.ToString()));
        throw;
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Can you make it a little clearer what the issue with the code is?

Comment: Yes John Bartels, is what I want. I tried to follow your example but the result is always empty.